# Problemas na requisição (Java - Spring Boot)

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, rest, restful

Eai galera, tudo tranquilo?
Tenho um código de uma API Rest que realiza o cadastro de cursos e alunos. Existe um relacionamento bidirecional.
N Alunos -> 1 Curso mapeado da seguinte forma:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "curso_id")
    private Curso curso;
```

1 curso -> N Alunos mapeado da seguinte forma:

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "curso_id")
    private List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Estou usando um banco H2 na aplicação para persistir os dados, porém, sinto que não estou conseguindo fazer a requisição da forma correta na hora de criar um aluno. Segue meu método de criação de aluno:

```
    @PostMapping("/aluno")
    public void create(@RequestBody Aluno aluno){
        alunoRepository.save(aluno);
    }
```

Json da requisição para criar o curso(funcionando corretamente):

```
{
    "nome": "Nutrição",
    "campus": "Campos Araguari"
}
```

Json da requisição para criar aluno(não funcionando corretamente):`

```
{
    "nome": "Fulaninho",
    "matricula": "745896",
    "curso_id": 1
}
```

Resultado do select:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou há um tempo travado e sinceramente não estou conseguindo encontrar o problema. Já tentei passar dentro do aluno um objeto curso com seu respectivo Id, também não funciona :(

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Alexsander, tudo depende da ordem que o seu projeto gira, se é em torno do usuário ou do curso, pelo que eu vi você precisa ter o curso já inserido no banco para depois poder inserir o aluno, outro ponto a se considerar, na sua classe aluno você possui a classe curso como atributo? se não pode ser isso, já que o SpringBoot resolve as relações desta forma assim o H2 hibernate consegue inserir os dados no banco, considerando [Curso 1 -> N Aluno]:

Aluno:

```
 public class Aluno {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="curso_id")
    private Curso curso;
    private String nome;
    private String matricula;
    
    
    //devidos metodos
    
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Curso getCurso() {
        return curso;
    }
    public void setCurso(Curso curso) {
        this.curso = curso;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }
    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Curso:

public class Curso {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
private String nome;
private String Campus; // ou private Campus campus;
@OneToMany
private ArrayList<Aluno> alunos;

//devidos metodos


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getCampus() {
    return Campus;
}
public void setCampus(String campus) {
    Campus = campus;
}
public ArrayList<Aluno> getAlunos() {
    return alunos;
}
public void setAlunos(ArrayList<Aluno> alunos) {
    this.alunos = alunos;
}
```

}

Acredito eu q isso resolve